# Handling large amounts of arbitrarily scheduled tasks in node

Tags: node.js, cron, scheduled-tasks, node-worker-threads

**Premise:** I have a calendar-like system that allows the creation/deletion of 'events' at a scheduled time in the future. The end goal is to perform an action (send message/reminder) prior to & at the start of the event. I've done a bit of searching & have narrowed down to what seems to be my two most viable choices

- Unix Cron Jobs
- [Bree](https://jobscheduler.net)

I'm not quite sure which will best suit my end goal though, and additionally, it feels like there *must* be some additional established ways to do things like this that I just don't have proper knowledge of, or that I'm entirely skipping over.

**My questions:**

- If, theoretically, the system were to be handling an arbitrarily large amount of 'events', all for arbitrary times in the future, which of these options is more practical system-resource-wise? Is my concern in this regard even valid?
- Is there any foreseeable problem with filling up a crontab with a large volume of jobs - or, in bree's case, scheduling a large amount of jobs?
- Is there a better idea I've just completely missed so far?

This mainly stems from bree's use of node 'worker threads'. I'm very unfamiliar with this concept
and concerned that since a 'worker thread' is spawned per every job, I could very quickly tie up all of my available threads and grind... something, to a halt. This, however, sounds somewhat silly & possibly wrong(possibly indicative of my complete lack of knowledge here), & thus, my question.

Thanks, Stark.

Comment: For a calendar-like system, it seems you could query your database to find all events occuring in the next hour, then create a `setTimeout()` for each one of those.  Then, an hour later, do the same thing again.  Then, upon any server restart, do the same thing again.  You don't really need to worry about events that aren't imminent.  They can just sit in the database until shortly before their time.  You will just need an efficient way to query the database to find events that are imminent and user a timer for them.

Comment: WorkerThreads are fairly heavy weight items in nodejs as they create a whole separate heap and a whole new instance of a V8 interpreter.  You would definitely not want a separate WorkerThread for each event.

Comment: @jfriend00 Your comment about WorkerThreads is exactly what I was concerned about, thank you so much for the confirmation. 

As to the solution, that's actually probably perfect for my use-case. I was wracking my brain for solutions earlier, & hadn't quite come up with something like that yet; I think that's probably exactly what I'll do now. If you want to post as an answer, feel free to & I'll mark it as solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a calendar-like system, it seems you could query your database to find all events occuring in the next hour, then create a setTimeout() for each one of those. Then, an hour later, do the same thing again. Then, upon any server restart, do the same thing again. You don't really need to worry about events that aren't imminent. They can just sit in the database until shortly before their time. You will just need an efficient way to query the database to find events that are imminent and user a timer for them.

WorkerThreads are fairly heavy weight items in nodejs as they create a whole separate heap and a whole new instance of a V8 interpreter. You would definitely not want a separate WorkerThread for each event.

---

I should add that timers in nodejs are very lightweight items and it is not problem to have lots of them.  They are just stored in a sorted linked list and only the insertion of a new timer takes a little bit more time (to do an insertion sort as it is added to the list) as the list gets longer.  There is no continuous run-time overhead because there are lots of timers.  The event loop, then just checks the first item in the linked list to see if it's time yet for the next timer to fire.  If so, it removes it from the head of the list and calls its callback.  If not, it goes about the rest of the event loop work items and will check the first item in the list again the next through the event loop.

Comment: Your insight is much appreciated. Thanks again!